# Stylesheet only applying to elements relative to the style element itself

Tags: html, css

*I'm sorry if this question seems uninformed and lacking own research, but I've tried searching anything I could think of on google but still couldn't find anything about it anymore.*

A while back, I recall reading something about styles relative to the stylesheet they were declared from. I am not entirely sure if this is indeed what was meant on the page I read it, but I have no idea where I read about it exactly, so I wouldn't know where to look to check it. Anyway, this is the impression I got from it:

What I am looking for is a way to make this only select the span inside the div that also has the style tag in it.

```
<div>
    <span class="special">Not red</span>
</div>
<div>
    <style>.special {color:red;}</style>
    <span class="special">Red</span>
</div>
```

I know this doesn't work, but I have no idea how to do this, or if it is even possible to insert a style tag within the body and then to apply styles either relative to that style tag.

If anyone has any idea on how this might be possible (without JavaScript), or if you're absolutely sure this is impossible to do without assigning seperate classes to the affected span, please tell me.

PS: the order in which the elements occur may differ, so `div + div .special {color:red;}` or `div:last-child .special {color:red;}` won't work.

Comment: you can use multiple class names in a field, fe `<span class="special redColor">`. It would make the work easier. Also, i don't recommend to use style tags in HTML. Please use a css sheet.

Comment: What you read about was the `scoped` attribute: `<style scoped> your css </style>`. Most of today's browsers do not support it, but in the future this will be a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `<style scoped>`

Here are a few links

- http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/
- http://caniuse.com/style-scoped (you'll want to be sure the browsers you are targeting can use it.)

So you nearly have it correct in your example, just add the `scoped` attribute.

Comment: The "scoped" attribute has been eliminated, removed from the specifications. The correct way is to use different classes for each element, rather than trying to work around name collisions ("special"/"special")

Answer (score 2):

Normal CSS would be to apply different classes to these spans. They're fundamentally different.

If you want to work around that, you could apply classes to their enclosing divs:

```
<div>
    <span class="special">Not red</span>
</div>
<div class="div-special">
    <span class="special">Red</span>
</div
```

And the CSS:

```
.div-special .special { color: red; }
```

**EDIT** You could add a second class to the second span and apply the color there `<span class="special colored-red">`